# Find all $x$ from real numbers such that $f$ is differentiable at $x$.

Tags: real-analysis

> Define $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ as $f(x) = |x+1|$. Find all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f$ is differentiable at $x$.

Comment: I think you mean to find $x$ such that $f$ is differentiable **at** $x$.

Comment: In other words, you want to find where the function $f(x)=|x+1|$ is differentiable. Hint: look at $x=-1$.

Comment: Yes, correct...

Comment: plot the graph of the given function

Comment: And edit the question according to Sahiba Arora's remark...

Comment: Also, the tag should be "real-analysis" and not "differential equations".

Comment: For x=-1 i get |h|/h what is equals to 1. Thus -1 is differenriable like every other real number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the piecewise function

$f(x)=-x-1$ if $x\le-1$

$f(x)=x+1$ if $x\ge-1$

Both functions are differentiable on their domain.

But when the functions are spliced together to form the absolute value, they are not differentiable together at $x=-1$.

We have $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to -1^{-}}f'(x)=-1$ and $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to -1^{+}}f'(x)=1$.

Because the two limits don't match, $f'(x)$ is not continuous at $x=-1$ and therefore $f(x)$ is not differentiable at $x=-1$. How tragic.

Therefore, $f(x)$ is differentiable for $x \in (-\infty, -1) U (-1, \infty)$.

Comment: thanks, how can i spot a non-differentiable function or a point in a function in general? are there any definitions?

Answer (score 0):

The function is:

$f(x)=x+1$ for $x\ge -1$

$f(x)=-x-1$ for $x< -1$

So at $x=-1$ the left derivative is $  f'(-1^-)=-1$ and the right derivative is  $  f'(-1^+)=1$.  So the function is not derivable at $x=-1$, but it is derivable for all other values of $x$ .